# Two IDEs have different results

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, easymock

My co-worker and I are working on the same project, but we use different IDEs. He uses Eclipse 3.4 and I use IntelliJ 8.0.

Recently I advocated using EasyMock, which uses CGLIB, for some unit tests on our project. I have not seen any problem setting breakpoints in IntelliJ on the partial mock objects generated by EasyMock, but my co-worker reports that he cannot set breakpoints in Eclipse on the partial mock objects generated by EasyMock because it reports the line number information is absent for the generated classes.

After hopelessly searching Google for an answer, I am hoping for hints from my friends on SO.

1. Any ideas on why IntelliJ works while Eclipse does not in this case?
2. Any clues for Eclipse configuration that might resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are the easy mock objects created by some ant script?  in that case the settings in eclipse have no relation to the generated debug line information  It would then be necessary to check the ant settings to see if there is some difference